# Where do I get this part for my v brake?

Tags: brakes

I lost small plastic "collar" part on the front v brake which goes around the spring and onto the post. Does anybody know where I can get another one?

[image: collar part]

Comment: Try your friendly local bike shop.  They may be able to dip into their junk box and find you something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably not going to find this part without cannibalizing a similar enough brake arm.

The parts you can find replacements for without having a sacrificial arm for V-brakes (*) are:

- Noodle
- Boot
- Mounting Bolt
- Brake pads/cartridges

If you need to replace/repair any other part of the V-brake, you're better off (and likely going to be) buying a new one.

(*) for most V-brakes; check the service manual for your particular model, though even if it is serviceable, you're unlikely to find the parts.

---

That being said, you might be able to make a suitable replacement on your own for the part in question with a bit of PVC tubing or some other plastic tubing cut to size and shaped appropriately.

Comment: Or find someone with a 3D printer and print it yourself in nylon or abs

Comment: That bit seems to be a mere cover for the spring and serves no real purpose apart from hiding the spring. You may do without.

Comment: Except the tension screw goes through it and often when the cover breaks, the tension screw doesn't work properly any more.

Comment: It depends on the V-brake, but for a good deal of Shimano V-brakes, this is not a cosmetic part (for the reason Noah states). You can use the brakes safely without them, but you do have more fidgety adjustment (not the end of the world).

Comment: @Noah Sutherland: The picture isn't very clear in that regard. The tension screw seems to be part of the brake arm.